# How to change inputText values on focus looses and before sending to server

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Hope you all will be fine. The scenerio is I have a form on which there is name inputText field. I want that if user type `'` in the name then it is replaced by `//`. I have made the replace function. But I don't know that how can I do it using ajax.
Like if I have input field like this

```html
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameError name"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="name" id="nameError" style="color: red" />
```

Now I want that if user types `'Basit'Mahmood'Ahmed'` in the name field then on focus looses the value becomes `//Basit//Mahmood//Ahmed//`. So when user presses on submit button then the `//Basit//Mahmood//Ahmed//` should be posted to the server, not the `'Basit'Mahmood'Ahmed'`.

How can I do it in JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a converter.

E.g.

```
@FacesConverter("userNameConverter")
public class UserNameConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return (String) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return (value != null) ? value.replaceAll("'", "//") : null;
    }

}
```

with

```html
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}" converter="userNameConverter">
```

The `getAsObject()` will run during validations phase and do the desired conversion before the model value is been updated and the view is been re-rendered.

Comment: Hi thanks :) one thing more. I am using code like this [code]<td><h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}"
                 converter="userNameConverter">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="nameError name" />
    </h:inputText>
</td>
<td><h:message for="name" id="nameError" style="color: red" /> </td> . and your ocnverter that you mention in your post. I want that when value retrun then message also show in next column. <h:message> column. How can i do it? by throwing converter excception ? Thanks

Comment: Use `context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), message)`.

Comment: public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

         context.addMessage(component.getClientId(), new FacesMessage("Hi how r u"));
         return (value != null) ? value.replaceAll("'", "//") : null;

     } //end of getAsObject()                                                                     This is working. Thank you very much